# Shorten a 32 char http session id down to 20 chars (truncate? hash?)

Tags: java, http, function, session, hash

My requirement is to send a 20 chars long http session id as a string value to a 3rd party script. So in Java I get the HttpServletRequest, then get the HttpSession and finally the ID which is 32 chars long and looks like this 2A5B2EF7B388159A6E5A7C038F6B694F.

Now to my question:
As I can only pass the session ID as a max. 20 char long url encoded string I obviously need to shorten the ID. How can I shorten the ID without raising the chance of conflicts too much?

If the ID really is random I theoretically could truncate it to 20 chars right? But since I don't exactly know how this ID is generated it may be better to use a hash function which breaks the ID down to 20 chars.

Do you have any suggestions for a hash function or some more info about the HttpSession ID that could help me in this specific case?

Thanks in advance.

**edit**
I forgot to mention that the id/parameter has to be url encoded. How about this approach:

I create a char[] array with all the unreserved percent encoding characters. I only take the unreserved chars because the reserved ones take up to 3 slots when encoded:
e.g. '/' is '%2F'

Then I create a byte array out of the hex string, which gives me a byte[16]
The value of the byte is then mapped (with wraparound) to the char[] array with the allowed characters.

```
StringBuilder shortenedSessionId = new StringBuilder();
char[] data = sid.toCharArray();
byte[] decodedHexData = Hex.decodeHex(data);

for (byte b : decodedHexData) {
    char mappedChar = allowedSessionIdChars[(b & 0xFF) % allowedSessionIdChars.length];
    shortenedSessionId.append(mappedChar);
}
```

The char[] allowedSessionIdChars contains letter A-Z, a-Z, 0-9 and -_.~

Comment: You could md5 hash the string and then use only the first 20 chars (of the 32 hex chars).

Comment: _"If the ID really is random I theoretically could truncate it to 20 chars right?"_ - of course not, because there are quite many (256^12) session ID's that share the same first 20 characters and differ in the remaining 12 characters.

Comment: When you say "20 char long string value", what exactly do you mean by "char"? Is it a C char, a value between 0 and 255, or is it only printable characters?

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström I mean printable chars.

Comment: If you want only A-Z, a-Z, 0-9 and -_.~ (66 total) it's not possible without collisions. Your domain consists of 16^32 keys. 20 characters with 66 possibilities for each span 66^20 keys. It's less than 16^32 inputs, thus no unique translation is possible. Use some good hash function to minimize the collisions. Even with uniform distribution you'll still have ~138 inputs mapped to the same output

Comment: @icepack Well, I guess this is acceptable, since an active HttpSession won't last for that long and there won't be so many users surfing simoultaneously..

Answer (score 5):

Each 2 characters in your hex string are an exact fit into a byte. So each character in the output can actually hold 2 input chars. Just traverse the input string, something like this:
`dst[i] = (src[2*i] << 8) + src[2*i+1]`. For input sized 36, you'll get an 18-characters string. That's the maximum lossless compression you can get since this is the maximum you can stuff into a single byte.

Comment: Null bytes might need special handling, and that won't necessarily show up as a problem until a session ID with 00 is tested

Comment: not sure why you think it is a script. It's tagged java. Besides, same issue exists on the uncompressed input. If it's a problem, it's unrelated to the question

Comment: From the question: " to a 3rd party script.". The same problem doesn't exist on uncompressed input because it's only numbers and A-F.

Comment: OP says it needs to be printable chars.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström see my comment under OP's question